# Get Intellisense to read function prototypes from different files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a class that is growing too big for a single file and would like to split it out into different files. I have got this working in a sample project, but Intellisense can't "see" functions in those other files

Using a sandbox as a sample project, I've managed to get functions to execute across files but Intellisense doesn't suggest these functions as options to use. I'm fairly new to JS but have been using the node_module  https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-tradeoffer-manager as inspiration

Example BigClass

```
module.exports = BigClass

function BigClass () {}

require('./expansion') // I've tried moving this about, to no avail

BigClass.prototype.doAThing = function () {
  console.log(`I did a thing`)
  this.doAnotherThing() // Intellisense doesn't suggest this as an option - but it's legit 
}
```

Example expansion.js

```
const BigClass = require('./index')

BigClass.prototype.doAnotherThing = function () {
  console.log(`I did another thing`)
}
```

I would expect that intellisense would suggest `doAnotherThing` as an option. Its legit code and executes as expected (prints "I did a thing" and "I did another thing").

My end goal is to to be able to split my 2000 line class up into smaller files and still have intellisense fully working as if it were in a single file, so if theres an easier way to achieve this (say using ES6 classes somehow) then I'm all ears